# How to solve $\ y'' + y = \sin(x) + \cos(2x) $?

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need to find the solution for

$$\ y'' + y = \sin(x) + \cos(2x) $$

general solution is $\ \{ \sin(x), \cos(x) \} $ and trying to "guess private solution:

$$\ y_p = Ax \sin(x) + Bx \cos(2x)  \\ y''_p = 2A \cos(x) -Ax\sin(x) -4B \sin(2x) +4Bx \cos(2x)  \\ then \\ 2A \cos(x) -Ax\sin(x) -4B \sin(2x) +4Bx \cos(2x) + Ax\sin(x) + Bx\cos(2x) = \sin(x) + \cos(2x) \\ 5Bx\cos(2x) -4B \sin(2x) + 2A\cos(x) = \sin (x) + \cos(2x)
 $$

I can't see how can I extract the $\ A, B $ as I have $\ 5Bx \cos(2x) $ and only $\ -4B \sin(2x) $ ? I tried using trig identities but couldn't come up with anything helpful.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$$\ y'' + y = \sin(x) + \cos(2x)\implies (D^2+1)y=\sin(x) + \cos(2x)$$where $D\equiv\frac{d}{dx}$

Complementary function (C.F.) $\quad = A\cos x+ B \sin x\qquad$where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants.

Particular Integral (P.I.)$\quad = \frac{1}{D^2+1} (\sin(x) + \cos(2x))$

$=\frac{x}{2D}\sin x-\frac{1}{3}\cos(2x)$

$=-\frac{x}{2}\cos x-\frac{1}{3}\cos(2x)$

So the general solution of the given differential equation is $$y(x)=\text{C.F.}+\text{P.I.}=A\cos x+ B \sin x-\frac{x}{2}\cos x-\frac{1}{3}\cos(2x)$$where $A,B$ are arbitrary constants.

---

For the Particular Integral (i.e., P.I.) of trigonometric functions  you have to follow the following rules:

> If $f(D)$ can be expressed as $\phi(D^2)$ and $\phi(-a^2)\neq 0$, then
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \sin ax=\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \sin ax = \frac{1}{\phi(-a^2)} \sin ax$
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \cos ax=\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \cos ax = \frac{1}{\phi(-a^2)} \cos ax$
>
> **Note:** If $f(D)$ can be expressed as $\phi(D^2)=D^2+a^2$, then $\phi(-a^2)= 0$.
>
> $1.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \sin ax =\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \sin ax=x\frac{1}{\phi'(D^2)} \sin ax= x \frac{1}{2D} \sin ax= -\frac{x}{2a} \cos ax$.
>
> $2.$ $\frac{1}{f(D)} \cos ax =\frac{1}{\phi(D^2)} \cos ax=x\frac{1}{\phi'(D^2)} \cos ax=  x \frac{1}{2D} \cos ax= \frac{x}{2a} \sin ax$.
>
> where $\phi'(D^2)\equiv\frac{d}{dD}\phi(D^2)$

Answer (score 2):

For the particular solution you need $$ Ax \sin x +Bx \cos x +C\sin(2x)+D\cos(2x)$$
 The cconstants are found by plugging this solution in your equation and identifying the coefficients on both sides.

Answer (score 1):

Your error is in the form of the particular solution. Homogeneous equation:

$$y''+y=0$$

...has solution $y=C_1\sin x + C_2\cos x$

So your particular solution should be:

$$y_p=Ax\sin x+Bx\sin x +C \sin(2x)+D\cos(2x)$$